# Magento 2.3: How to set the default swatch selection pro-grammatically on product listing page?

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, swatches, product-listing

I want to implement the selection of swatch options in a way that by default it should be selected 2nd swatch on listing pages.

Attribute name is **color**.

[image]

I looked over the following Blocks but not finding any clue.

```
vendor\magento\module-swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php 
vendor\magento\module-swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable.php
```

Also, checked  `vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\web\js\swatch-renderer.js` and found below code. But this does not work and in JS all other functions are start with underscore(_) not accessible.

```
if (firstSwatch.length) {
    $(firstSwatch).focus();
}
```

In some cases, **Color** and **Size** will be there but we want to select only 2nd position of color if have.

Answer (score 2):

Detail information can be found in this [link](https://www.satz24.com/post/post-rwLm2SqQ/How-to-Auto-Select-First-Child-or-nth-child-Product-of-Magento-2-Configurable-Product-in-Product-List-Page?kanhaiya5590)

To achieve this (2nd position), we can do by Override **`swatch-renderer.js`** in our theme
**Till Magento v2.3.3** -  `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

**Magento v2.3.4 onwords** - `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

Theme file location is -  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`

find **`_RenderControls()`** function
update below code from **// START - Custom code** ...   **// End - Custom code** at the end of this function : or follow below

```
_RenderControls: function () {
    var $widget = this,
        container = this.element,
        classes = this.options.classes,
        chooseText = this.options.jsonConfig.chooseText;
 
    $widget.optionsMap = {};
 
    // [... Existing code...]
 
    // Rewind options
    $widget._Rewind(container);
 
    //Emulate click on all swatches from Request
    $widget._EmulateSelected($.parseQuery());
    $widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());
 
 
    // START - Custom code
    if ($widget.inProductList) { // for product list page only 
        var defaultSelectCode = 'color',
            defaultPosition = 2,
            codeNotExistInFilter = true;
        $.each($.parseQuery(), $.proxy(function (attributeCode) {
            if(defaultSelectCode === attributeCode){
                codeNotExistInFilter = false;
            }
 
        }, this));
        
        if(codeNotExistInFilter) {
            $widget.element.find('.' + this.options.classes.attributeClass +
                '[attribute-code="' + defaultSelectCode + '"]  [option-id]:nth-child('+defaultPosition+')').trigger('click');
        }
    }
    // End - Custom code
}
```

**Note:**  **`defaultPosition`** = 1,2,3,... [any number position we can set]

above share detail done via **`overriding swatch-renderer.js`** in our theme but we can override this file in better way and update/add above shared code via js mixin  - [devdocs js_mixins - extend-jquery-widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#extend-jquery-widget) - **`'mage.SwatchRenderer'`**.

Please share any thought or input if need any further help/support on this.